# Problems creating a full text index on a table with 2 primary key

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with schema like

```
CREATE TABLE [ArticleDefinitionProperty](
    [ArticleDefinitionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyValue] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ArticleDefinitionProperty] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleDefinitionId] ASC,
    [PropertyTypeId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

When I try to creating a full text index on this table. It's show error :

> A unique column must be defined on this table/view.

Any idea how to fix that?. Thanks

Comment: Please provide the code that you tried to creating a full text index on this table

Comment: I use Full-Text Indexing Wizard to create a full text index on this table. But seem it just allow only one unique column not for composite key

Comment: You need to start thinking seriously about your schema. One does not randomly throw columns together to create a table. In addition, names matter. I'll guess that you originally had defined ArticleDefinitionId as an identity - that is what the name implies. Now you intend to populate it during insert. Unfortunately, it is also the leading column in your primary key (which the database will implement as a clustered index). This column will likely not be very useful as the lead column in that index. And where is your foreign key? You have more work to do.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have not and can not have 2 PK defined on the same table.

What you have is 2 columns-PK, i.e. your PK key is composed of 2 columns.

But the requirement is

> KEY INDEX index_name Is the name of the unique key index on
>   table_name. The KEY INDEX must be a unique, **single-key**, non-nullable
>   column. Select the smallest unique key index for the full-text unique
>   key. For the best performance, we recommend an integer data type for
>   the full-text key.

So you should add this **single-key** unique column. This can be just enumerator (easiest way) or you can define it based on existing columns, for example like this: 
`ArticleDefinitionId * 10000000000 + PropertyTypeId` (`decimal(20,0)`)